# Why do I get rsync error 20 when trying to customize Ubuntu?

Tags: mount, iso, rsync

when trying to customize my ubuntu desktop live iso i'm coming across an rsync error in the first stages of [the tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Extract_the_CD_.iso_contents).

when I execute: 
    `sudo rsync --exclude=/casper/filesystem.squashfs -a mnt/ extract-cd` 
The copy starts with no output. I left this running for around 40 minutes and have assumed that something went wrong in the copy.
    `sudo rsync -ax mnt/ extract-cd`
I tried this command too and I got the same error after pressing ctrl+c.

This is the error I am getting:

```
    rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(549) [sender=3.0.9]
```

any suggestions/tips would be welcome

**Edit**

This is the link to the output from the command you suggested I run:[rsync output](http://pastebin.com/gQjxVj9Y)

I looked at your recommendation of using ubuntu-builder. I am using ssh to access the computer with no possibility of using an UI.

I tried the *ubuntu customization kit* this morning running the by running the `uck-remaster-unpack-iso`. My understandinf of this command is that it runs a script similar to what I was typing in by hand. This command also stops producing output and I exited it after 10 minutes(No error output was given).

Answer (score 2):

The error is simply caused by your pressing Ctrl+C to interrupt *rsync*.

The command should work; since it's not, please try running this and let us know what the output is:

```
sudo rsync --exclude=/casper/filesystem.squashfs -a -nPh mnt/ extract-cd
```

The only difference is the additional `-nPh` option:
- `-n` indicates a dry run, or a simulation; rsync will simulate what happens, including any errors, without actually copying any data.
- `-Ph` shows the progress file-by-file in "human" readable (i.e. kilobytes, megabytes, etc.) form.

---

**Please note:** The Ubuntu customization wiki is terribly outdated. I highly recommend usin a more modern, user-friendly customization solution that takes care of extracting, mounting, chrooting, etc. for you.

[**Ubuntu Builder**](http://code.google.com/p/ubuntu-builder/) is my tool of choice. Please see [**this answer** of mine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd/157562#157562) for a more-hands-on tutorial of using Ubuntu Builder to customize 12.04.

Comment: the ubuntu builder seems like a useful application, I will test it out when I can use my ui again

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the problem, There is another problem on my computer causing [very low write speeds to ntfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165468/slow-write-speeds-to-ntfs). Therefore When I tried to run *rsync* the copy simply would not complete in a feasible amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

After installed below packages, the problem solved.

sudo apt-get install libgcrypt11

sudo apt-get install libgcrypt11:i386

Comment: Why `libgcrypt11` and  `libgcrypt11:i386`?