# Slow write speeds to ntfs

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, ntfs

When writing to my *ntfs* partition I am getting very low speeds( When reading however I'm getting my maximum speeds):

```
589824   3%   60.20kB/s    0:04:06
```

This example is using

```
rsync --progress [File] [Destination]
```

Where I am making a copy of the file in the same directory.

I am mounting my *ntfs* partition using fstab:

```
/dev/sda6 /mnt/data ntfs-3guid=1000,gid=11000,umask=0022,sync,auto,nosuid,rw,nouser 0 0
```

I am not sure if this is relevant but I was recently looking at the [Power Tweaking](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks) tips provided on the Ubuntu wiki and I believe that these situations may correlate.

Grub Conf:

```
GRUB_BACKGROUND=/boot/grub/gbackground.jpg
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

The power tweak that I believe is causing the problem is the [ALPM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagementALPM).

**Note:** My write speeds to my ntfs patition were absolutely fine until about yesterday when I started fiddling with the power tweak(s)

I am using one drive with multiple partitions, so it cannot be a hardware error, this is also because My dual boot in windows can access the drive at normal speeds.

Answer (score 4):

It's the `sync` option that you show in your `fstab` line that's doing it. This is a common problem when using an external USB drive that uses usbmount. From `/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf`:

```
#############################################################################
# WARNING!                                                                  #
#                                                                           #
# The "sync" option may not be a good choice to use with flash drives, as   #
# it forces a greater amount of writing operating on the drive. This makes  #
# the writing speed considerably lower and also leads to a faster wear out  #
# of the disk.                                                              #
#                                                                           #
# If you omit it, don't forget to use the command "sync" to synchronize the #
# data on your disk before removing the drive or you may experience data    #
# loss.                                                                     #
#                                                                           #
# It is highly recommended that you use the pumount command (as a regular   #
# user) before unplugging the device. It makes calling the "sync" command   #
# and mounting with the sync option unnecessary---this is similar to other  #
# operating system's "safely disconnect the device" option.                 #
#############################################################################
```

So just remove the `sync` option from `fstab` or change it to `async`. If you are hotplugging change the following line in that `/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf` from:

```
MOUNTOPTIONS="sync,noexec,nodev,noatime,nodiratime"
```

to

```
MOUNTOPTIONS="noexec,nodev,noatime,nodiratime"
```

And don't forget to safely unmount your drive before unplugging.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me once. I had edited the *fstab* to automount the NTFS partition automatically at boot. Restoring the file to before editing it did the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I actually just gave up and re installed Ubuntu, not sure if I should put that as an answer as it's not really a fix...