# Transferring from USB to NTFS hard drive is really slow

Tags: 12.04, usb, hard-drive, ntfs, fstab

I have a second hard drive that I've installed on my system, and copying files from the USB to the hard drive is extremely slow (about 70kB/sec).

Here is my `/etc/fstab` entry:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/Storage ntfs uid=rhys,gid=users,auto,user,exec,rw,sync 0 0
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Are you using usb 1.0 or usb2.0?

Comment: I've tried the USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports.

Comment: Are you copying several tiny files, or rather big ones?

Comment: I'm copying big files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as though switching the flag from `sync` to `async` fixes the issue.

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/Storage ntfs uid=rhys,gid=users,auto,user,exec,rw,async 0 0
```

Comment: See how to deal with hotplug USB devices in http://askubuntu.com/a/500562/237134

Answer (score 2):

Actually, asyncronous copy shouldn't change the speed. It would look like that because the copy happens in background, but you won't be able to unmount the drive any sooner than before. At least with syncronous tranfer when it says "Done", it really *is* done... but the downside is that the pop-up "Copying" box will hang around for ages.

Comment: That's simply not true, whatever you might think in principle. Try changing the option and see the difference for a large file. From `/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf`: 'WARNING! The "sync" option may not be a good choice to use with flash drives, as it forces a greater amount of writing operating on the drive. This makes the writing speed considerably lower and also leads to a faster wear out of the disk.'