# Copying files with nautilus bottlenecking the whole system

Tags: nautilus, files, ntfs, transfer

When I copy files using nautilus, most recently from a NTFS external hdd to a FAT32 usb drive, the system crawls to a stop.  Everything, even TTY login is affected.  It's impossible to use the machine.  I have a new computer, 3rd gen i7, 6 gigs of RAM, and I feel like I shouldn't be having this issue.  Has to be a bug.  Often times the destinations, as I said above, are both external.  My OS is installed on a SSD, and I have a second internal HDD.  Copying from these seems fine.

Running Ubuntu 13.10, clean install, 64-bit, fully updated.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is a kernel bug for sure, it has been reported for a while, typically in association with ntfs. As far as I know, the exact details have not been determined, but my understanding is that is has to do with write buffers filling followed by slow write. There is a nice overview here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/283136/why-is-usb-file-transfer-so-slow-in-12-10 , but for details you will have to look at various kernel bugs. Not sure if that exactly applies to you as the exact bug is unknown.

Comment: But that doesn't seem to deal with the system lag.  *Everything* to do with the system (TTYs, LDM, Unity...) practically stopped.  This seems to be a more serious issue than slow copies, as I literally cannot use my computer as the copy crawls along.