# Problem while coping files in USB drive

Tags: 12.04, usb-drive, ms-dos

I've a USB 2.0 drive. Today while I coping some media files in the pendrive, I found that It stucked in middle. I'd wait for half an hour, it remains unchanged! I thought that this is may be problem with my pendrive. I tried with another pendrive and got the same result!! What can I do?

Comment: What file system is on the usb ? if it is NTFS, it is a long standing bug in the kernel with no consistent solution. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/283136/why-is-usb-file-transfer-so-slow-in-12-10

Comment: Filesystem type:  msdos