# Slow USB Transfer rates in gnome

Tags: usb, ubuntu-gnome, transfer, i3-wm

I have an amazing USB transfer rate when I use `unity`. But when I am running `gnome with i3` or only `i3`, I get terrible USB transfer rates. How to fix this?

p.s.: `i3` is a windows manager, and not the processor.

Comment: What software do you use to copy to USB? Nautilus? Some other file manager? `cp`? What's the read/write performance of the USB drive when you use tools like `dd [io]flag=direct` or some other disk performance tool like Gnome Disks?

Comment: Maybe there is no way of fixing it: http://askubuntu.com/a/284053/21195 , maybe...

Answer (score 0):

Check the USB Driver version. In case your USB device 2.0 --> Port 3.0 means its supported 2.0 Speed, Its depends upon your motherboard specification / USB port manufacturer. So its will depend upon **your motherboard**.

> Don't mention **I3 it is the Processor of your system**,
>
> So check the motherboard. In-case 3.0 below > > older version means update the motherboard hardware.

Comment: Actually [i3 is a window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I3_%28window_manager%29) in this case.

Comment: @TheSchwa: Yes i3 is a window manager. Any help on how to solve the above?